# Appengine Slowness

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces

I am frequently getting the following error while accessing my app from appengine. can somebody know what is the reason for this?

Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (216e5897c4ca40e3) started at 2013/02/21 04:27:45.277 UTC and was still executing at 2013/02/21 04:28:44.702 UTC.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about AppEngine slowness. What is happening is that you are facing a deadline that AppEngine has in place for certain kinds of calls.

From the documentation "A request handler has a limited amount of time to generate and return a response to a request, typically around 60 seconds. Once the deadline has been reached, the request handler is interrupted. The Java runtime environment interrupts the servlet by throwing a com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException. "

So what this means is that you are invoking most likely a request URL and it has reached a limit of 60 seconds but not yet completed its task and sent a response.

If you look at the exception you have put "Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (216e5897c4ca40e3) started at 2013/02/21 04:27:45.277 UTC and was still executing at 2013/02/21 04:28:44.702 UTC." - you can see that 60 seconds deadline has been reached: 04:27:45 - 04:28:44.702

So look at your code and try to return back earlier. If you think you need more time, look at [Cron Jobs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) that have a limit of 10 minutes or for more complex requirements, you have [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/).

Comment: But the same request in my local machine just takes less than 2 seconds to respond and both local and live applications have same kind of data to be returned as response, not only that a simple basic request also some times behaves in the same way which returns just login page. It happens very frequently but not always

Comment: @user1614862 If it's not that often you should also be aware that when the application just wakes up (after new deployment, or new instance) it takes sometime and it can take more than a minute.. It shouldn't but it happens..

Comment: It is always happening, after so many days also the problem continues..here is the url for the same.     http://ezeeappointerr.appspot.com/appointment.jspx

Comment: The likeliest issue here is your application startup is slow (class path scanning etc), and a medium length request + start up exceeds the timeout threshold. You can see in your logs what was going on when the request timed out.

Comment: Server warmup also need to be taken into consideration. Usually appengine time out is 60 seconds. If your request takes more that that prefer going to a backend request. Appengine has interesting asynchronous calls which makes asynchronous http calls

Answer (score 0):

If these requests are normally fast, it could be that the ones failing are the first requests to hit a new instance. This means a lot of class loading  can cause the request to go long.

Consider using warmup requests to avoid this, make sure your warmup request hits the same classes/frameworks as used by this method:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_Warmup_requests